# Definite or zero article in front of adjective

Tags: adjectives, definite-articles, zero-article

My linguistic instinct (for whatever it is worth to non-native writers) tells me that the sentence

> The French historiography ascribes to the first legendary king of Poldevia…

"sounds" wrong while the sentence

> French historiography ascribes to the first legendary king of Poldevia…

"sounds" right. Is my instinct wrong? And if it is correct, could someone state a formal rule for when the definite article is used in front of an adjective followed by the name of a discipline or situation?

Similar example:

> French cuisine is known world-wide

which sounds OK, or

> The French cuisine is known world-wide

which sounds wrong…?

Comment: It's not "wrong" in the strict sense of the word. Prefacing _French historiography_ with the definite article simply means that there are (perhaps) other historiographies which (perhaps) don't _ascribes to the first legendary..._  **The** in that case sets apart _the French historiography_ from other such historiographies. The _sans-the_ version is okay as well. Likewise in your _cuisine_ example, **the** is optional.

Comment: I think your instincts are sharp - these examples sound more natural and less formal without the "the." 
In other cases, a "the" sounds more natural, perhaps particularly in the case of cities and states, where you can use the name of the locality as an adjective.  E.g. "The Berlin nightlife is insane" or "The L.A. air is so polluted you can hardly breathe."

Comment: Thanks, I do realize now that one would use "The French historiography" as a means to distinguish it with some other historiography mentioned earlier…!

Comment: @yannis it is already distinguished by "French": historiography and cuisine are both uncountable nouns and as such, they do not require a determiner. As you point out "the French historiography" would be used to distinguish it **from** some other historiography mentioned earlier. However, there is no indication that this has been done.